# Python Twisted Custom DNS

Tags: python, dns, twisted

I am new to the Twisted framework for python. I am playing around with a customer DNS server and I want to know how to located the SRC_IP of the DNS Request.

I am using the following script: http://twisted.readthedocs.org/en/latest/names/howto/custom-server.html

Specifically the one that dynamically resolves and want to know how I can located the source IP of the Request. 
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not being overly familiar with twisted, I don't know if this is the *best* way. I suspect that what I propose below is not because operating directly on the sockets doesn't feel right, but here it goes.

Subclass `server.DNSServerFactory` and override the `handleQuery()` method, for example:

```
import socket
from twisted.internet.address import IPv4Address

class MyDNSServerFactory(server.DNSServerFactory):

    def handleQuery(self, message, protocol, address):
        if protocol.transport.socket.type == socket.SOCK_STREAM:
            self.peer_address = protocol.transport.getPeer()
        elif protocol.transport.socket.type == socket.SOCK_DGRAM:
            self.peer_address = IPv4Address('UDP', *address)
        else:
            print "Unexpected socket type %r" % protocol.transport.socket.type

        print "Got message from : %r" % self.peer_address
        return server.DNSServerFactory.handleQuery(self, message, protocol, address)
.
.
.

factory = MyDNSServerFactory(
    clients=[DynamicResolver(), client.Resolver(resolv='/etc/resolv.conf')]
)
```

Things to worry about:

1. IPV6 addresses
2. Direct use of `socket` seems underhanded.
3. Does socket.SOCK_STREAM always imply a TCP connection?

There are other ways to do it, e.g. subclass `dns.DNSDatagramProtocol` and override `datagramReceived(self, data, addr)` to get the client UDP address. TCP client addresses would be gotten by subclassing and overriding `server.DNSServerFactory.connectionMade(self, protocol)` and getting the peer's address with `protocol.transport.getPeer()`.

---

**Updated answer to make peer address available in DynamicResolver**

Modify `MyDNSServerFactory.handleQuery()` to set `peer_address` for resolvers that have a `peer_address` attribute:

```
class MyDNSServerFactory(server.DNSServerFactory):

    def handleQuery(self, message, protocol, address):
        if protocol.transport.socket.type == socket.SOCK_STREAM:
            self.peer_address = protocol.transport.getPeer()
        elif protocol.transport.socket.type == socket.SOCK_DGRAM:
            self.peer_address = IPv4Address('UDP', *address)
        else:
            print "Unexpected socket type %r" % protocol.transport.socket.type

        print "Got message from : %r" % self.peer_address

        # Make peer_address available to resolvers that support that attribute
        for resolver in self.resolver.resolvers:
            if hasattr(resolver, 'peer_address'):
                resolver.peer_address = self.peer_address

        return server.DNSServerFactory.handleQuery(self, message, protocol, address)
```

Add the following `peer_address` property to class `DynamicResolver`:

```
    def __init__(self):
        self._peer_address = None

    @property
    def peer_address(self):
        return self._peer_address

    @peer_address.setter
    def peer_address(self, value):
        self._peer_address = value
```

Now you can access `peer_address` in `DynamicResolver.query()`, e.g.

```
    def query(self, query, timeout=None):
        print "In DynamicResolver.query(): self.peer_address = %r" % self.peer_address
        if self._dynamicResponseRequired(query):
            return defer.succeed(self._doDynamicResponse(query))
        else:
            return defer.fail(error.DomainError())
```

Comment: Another quick questions if I may; How do I get the the contents of self.peer_address to be available in my DynamicResolver() Class?

Comment: Yea... Touching `socket` makes everyone super sad.

Comment: @Jean-PaulCalderone : OK, so is other way (subclassing DNSDatagramProtocol and DNSServerFactory) better? Both methods seem inelegant to me.

Comment: @pjf - hhhmmm `DynamicResolver` is accessible from a`MyDNSServerFactory` instance in the `self.resolver.resolvers` list. It's going to be ugly, but you could add a property to DynamicResolver for `peer_address`, and set it from `handleQuery` by iterating over `self.resolver.resolvers` and setting `peer_address` for those resolvers that have a `peer_address` attribute.

Comment: @pjf - Answer updated to make the peer address available to DynamicResolver.

Comment: thaks very much for that. Works as expected. Unfortunately my skills dont really allow me at this stage to understand why this is "ugly" or touching sockets makes everyone super sad. This is of a POC rather than production code so at this stage it works fine.

Comment: This might be a good enhancement request to raise in the Twisted issue tracker.